# Way to design table for this kind of data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a employee table and status table. In employee table i have his id and name. and in status i store his status for various months of a year.

It never ends i.e. starting from current year to more year to come by it will keep on growing i.e. each row represents a status for a month and a year. So this takes hell lot of time to load a data for 12 month on screen as its 1 to many relationship.

So i was thinking to store this data in a serialized manner in same table as employee table i.e. key will be month_year and value will be its status. So if i do this will this table grow large to create space problems?.

And what data type should i use if i store serialize data and store in it. Because this application can be used for 3-4 years also. so it comes upto 48 months data in a array and same as serialized in table.

**** Update *****

If this month is November, I will shown on screen data from this year October to next year October. So this is the biggest problem.

**** Update2 ***

This is how i should show my data on the screen i.e. for each employee 12 months status. So i enter the problem of nested queries in my php code. Get a employee in loop enter the second table and take all his data and show.

[image]

Comment: does the query take a long time?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 - Yup, its taking more time. So thinking of new database table designs.

Comment: can you post the create table statements, and the query?

Comment: I don't know y this question got a negative marking. Is this not a valid question ?
@DarkSquirrel42 - i want to create new table with data as a serialized array in table. So wanted to know if size will become any problem and what should i choose as column data type for such things.

Comment: If possible post the Logical data model representation and your query used. and data size expected at each table. According to your question if your emp to status mapping has one to many relation; and by what u mentioned, the data structure should have 12 status (for each month) per employee. and this kind of data is not a big headache for querying.

Comment: i guess it has been downvoted because you are working in the wrong direction ... show the structure and the query ... maybe your tables need proper indexing ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42  - since i was working in wrong direction i came here and posted question for a proper solution right?

Comment: Embrace the downvote. What is the attach image does ? Is so tiny and  unreadable.

Comment: @ajreal  - This is how my screen will appear. So 1st column is all employee names and rest columns are 12 month status information of the employees.

Comment: I think my answer has most of the element. You can always use PHP to put `&nbsp;` if a value is absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is a bad choice.
You can consider normalization like this way :-

```
employee ( id, name ...);
employee_status (employee_id, year_month int(6), status boolean);
```

To get list of employ status from October to next October :-

```
select e.id, e.name, es.year_month, es.status
from employee as e
inner join employee_status as es
on e.id=es.employee_id
where es.year_month between "201110" and "201210";
```

Comment: Are you sure "es.year_month between "201110" and "201210";" . Does it not require date format ???

Comment: Yes. If you application does not require the day information (you did not mention in your question), is safe to ignore. Of course, you must store the data in `YYYYMM`

Comment: one small doubt. Can i do like (es.year between '2011' and '2012') and (es.month between '10' and '10')

Comment: There is no year field. Since is 6 digit integer, `201101 and 201299` work. Of course, this is work too `201101 and 201212`. Avoid LIKE if possible

Comment: I am asking because i have stored my month and year information in 2 different fields earlier. So asked can i write query for that also?

Comment: Yes, you can. Is just a derived from year_month.

Comment: if i try to store value like 01 or 02 for my month field i am unable to do that. And query like "where (es.year between '2011' and '2012') and (es.month between '10' and '10') " does not yield me proper result.

Comment: When you break into two fields, you have to glue back the year and month together. That's the reason why I suggest **year_month**, get it?

Comment: - yup got it. Earlier i had done wrong way. I did not know 201101 will also work in between clause. So i will correct it now.

Comment: Your report is for monthly (sort of group-by month), I dun think is benefits much. year_month is using most precise format. If using date, you have to duel with day( some months are 31, some are 30, some is 28...) However, date data type is using 3 bytes, integers are using 4 bytes.

Comment: since i am displaying second table data in a single row format on screen, i still run into problem of using 2 queries which slows my application again.

Answer (score 1):

In your status table, you create 15 columns:

1. 12 to represent each month (default is NULL)
2. 1 for the year INT type
3. 1 for the PK of the table
4. 1 for the FK to the user table

When you are storing the status, you simply change the month column from NULL to whatever your status is (this could be stored directly in this table, or could be a FK to another table).

To show your results for a year, its simply:

`SELECT * FROM status WHERE year = 2011 AND user_id = 1;`

You return one row, with a status for each month. You can then filter on IS NULL to get only those months for which you have a status.

Your table will only store one row for each employee that has a status for a year.

Comment: That wont work out for me. Because say this month is November. So on screen i will be showing like data from October to next year October. so there is the exact problem.